How to have fixed positions in kivy?
im trying to make a gui with kivy and keep positions fixed so for example when i resize the window i want to like see full text not half of it, heres my code:
<MyLayout>:
    FloatLayout:
        size:root.width,root.height 
        AsyncImage:
            source:'log.png'
            fit_mode:'fill'
        Label:
            text:"text:"
            size_hint:None,None
            pos_hint:{'x':0.06 ,'top':0.8}
            color:(0,0,0,1)
            font_size:30
            bold:True
          
        TextInput:
            size_hint:0.2,0.05
            pos_hint:{'x':0 ,'top':0.72}
        Label:
            text:"text:"
            font_size:30
            size_hint:None,None
            pos_hint:{'x':0.06 ,'top':0.6}
            color:(0,0,0,1)
            bold:True
        TextInput:
            size_hint:0.2,0.05
            pos_hint:{'x':0 ,'top':0.52}
        Button:
            text:"submit"
            italic:True
            size_hint:0.2,0.1
            pos_hint:{'x':0 ,'top':0.4}

I want to stay using the floatLayout to keep things in this order.

Try adding size: self.texture_size to each of the Labels.

And for each TextInput try:
size_hint:0.2,None             height: self.minimum_height
